# ASP.NET MVC and Entity framework - List as a property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

with entity framework, how should I load object from an object list ? Example.

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Corporation Corp { get; set; }
}

public class Corporation 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

// And now, when I get a Corporation class from entity framework,
//I can't access the Phones. I get an error: The value canot be null.
_db.Corporations.First().Name; // Works
_db.Corporations.First().Phones.First().Type; // Fails
```

How should I load the List properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mark the related entities as virtual to enable lazy loading by default.

```
class Corporation
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual List<Phone> Phones {get;set;}
}
class Phone
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual Corporation Corp {get;set;}
}
```